# How to get total billing amount with azure billing API

Tags: c#, api, azure

I have to display total billing amount for a Azure subscription. Currently I am using [Resource Usage API (Preview)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt219003.aspx) and [Resource RateCard API(Preview)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt219005.aspx) which is giving me very large  detailed data for Rate for each meter and its usage.
As per [this](https://github.com/Azure/azure-content/blob/master/articles/billing-usage-rate-card-partner-solution-cloudyn.md) article, I've to multiply Rate card details with the Usage Details.

As in my case, I've to show only total billing amount lets say 500 USD, its more than what I required and includes lot of manual work.

Is there any simple way to directly request total amount.

**Calling Usage API:**

`string requesturl = String.Format("https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{0}/providers/Microsoft.Commerce/UsageAggregates?api-version=2015-06-01-preview&reportedstartTime=2015-05-15+00%3a00%3a00Z&reportedEndTime=2015-05-16+00%3a00%3a00Z", subscriptionI`d);

**Calling RateCard API:**

```
string requesturl = String.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}/{3}",


"https://management.azure.com",
                   "subscriptions",
                   subscriptionId,
                   "providers/Microsoft.Commerce/RateCard?api-version=2015-06-01-preview&$filter=OfferDurableId eq 'MS-AZR-0121p' and Currency eq 'USD' and Locale eq 'en-US' and RegionInfo eq 'US'");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saurabh - unfortunately, we don't have an API that gives you the outstanding bill / running total of open billing period, but the combination of Usage and RateCard API can get you close.

We are actively discussing this scenario, but you might also want to reach out to 2 partners who have done the integration with the 2 Azure Billing APIs, that might be interested in building out the "get outstanding bill" API - Cloudyn and Cloud Cruiser.

Comment: Do work for MS Azure? If so, it would be helpful if you included the relevant information in your profile to help validate statements where you represent MS Azure, re: _"unfortunately, we don't have an API that gives you..."_

Comment: My Microsoft email is already listed on the StackExchange profile (mobandyo@microsoft.com) - perhaps I missed a flag somewhere in the profile?

Comment: Great to see you helping out here! FWIW, your profile doesn't show your email address and when I looked at your profile earlier, it didn't have anything in your summary. Glad you updated it; I'm sure folks here looking for help with Azure will benefit from your participation.